# Function components do not support contextType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

> Function components do not support contextType.

I encountered an issue when trying to add context to a React component that was wrapped with a React Router `withRouter(...)` function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import UserContext from './UserContext'
class Toolbar extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>username: this.context.username</div>
    )
  }
}
Toolbar.contextType = UserContext
export default withRouter(Toolbar)
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution to this issue is simply switch the last two lines like so:

```
export default withRouter(Toolbar)
Toolbar.contextType = UserContext
```